# Virtual ISIS Scanner

Tags: driver, imaging, image-scanner

In order to more efficiantly develop Imaging based applicatitions it would really help if I had a virtual ISIS driver that simulated a scanner bur instead read from the file system.

I can find TWAIN drivers that do this but, no matter how much time I waste, I just can't seem to find the same thing for ISIS.

Does anyone know of where I can find one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a virtual ISIS driver call SPEW.  I have a copy I can share with you. I just need to know the best way to get it to you (email, FTP location, etc)

Comment: I just sent a zip file with them.  I hope they help.

Comment: I don't especially want to post contact information here, but can you please make this available through a link of some sort?  Any of the numerous filesharing services would work, or even posting it from a Dropbox account.  That would definitely get an up-vote from me.

Comment: Just put these drivers in the normal pixtran directory with the other drivers.  The directory used to be \windows\pixtran.  

From there you will see a new scanner pop up in the select scanner dialog.

Comment: I am also looking for ISIS virtual Scanner to test x64 compatibility. Can you provide me? or any guide where to find?